# scikit learn prediction from coef_

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to generate prediction from fitted model (using scikit-learn, a simple linear regression using MultiTaskLasso). I assume coef_ stores the weight of feature. Suppose there are 5 labels and 200 features, it should be 5*200 in 2D. What I did is:
(in python) prediction = np.dot(X_test,coef_.T) + intercept_ . But it seems there is something wrong. When I switch to using scikit-learn's function predict(X_test), the result is right. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

The difference is only this step, when I use predict, it is right; when I use my code, it's wrong.

Comment: Can you provide an error traceback? What you are doing is correct if you are using dense matrices. With sparse matrices, this may need to be adapted.

Comment: Thanks. I did some modification and it works now. However, I am not sure what wrong previously. I guess it is related to numpy 1D array (it is always a line array instead of column). Can you specify sparse matrix? Any link I can read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `predict` works, then [`sklearn.linear_model.decision_function`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L136) works:

```
def decision_function(self, X):
    """Decision function of the linear model.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape = (n_samples, n_features)
        Samples.

    Returns
    -------
    C : array, shape = (n_samples,)
        Returns predicted values.
    """
    X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=['csr', 'csc', 'coo'])
    return safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,
                           dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
```

It does the same thing you propose but handles sparse matrices gracefully. If none of your matrices are sparse, then you should check `X_test` again.